# SUM a date column with where clause and grouped by

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have this SQL script which tries to compute all time (format is: 00:00:00) and sum it all up if it meets the criteria of WHERE and then I tried to group it.

If my understanding is correct, if I have 01:00:00 to 05:00:00 from Jan 1 to 5 then I want is to show 15:00:00 for Jan 1 and 15:00:00 for Jan 2 and so forth.

here's the script

```
SELECT  PLATENO,
    SUM(DOWNTIME) as DOWNTIME
FROM    TBLTIMETURNER
WHERE   MOTOTR= 'ON'
GROUP BY PLATENO
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is easiest done in some units, for instance, seconds:

```
select plateno, sum(datediff(second, 0, downtime)) as downtime
from TBLTIMETURNER
where MOTOTR= 'ON'
group by plateno;
```

You can convert this back to a `datetime` and then to a `time`, by using:

```
select plateno, cast(dateadd(second, 0, sum(datediff(second, 0, downtime))) as time) as downtime
from TBLTIMETURNER
where MOTOTR= 'ON'
group by plateno;
```

Comment: I met this error Sir, `The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.`

Comment: @Dodgeball . . . Change `second` to `minute`.